# ATMEGA328PB and ATMEGA328P: can be exchanged on a design?

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, flash

I'm working on a PCB design where I was using ATMEGA328P. Right now it is impossible to get it from any distribuitor, and I think that the best option is to replace it with an ATMEGA328PB (PCBGOGO says that ATMEGA328PB's stock is fine). On my PCB design I have TX and RX lines to flash it via FTDI (by Arduino UNO board without ATMEGA328P) and MISO/MOSI/CLK lines to burn the bootloader.

Can I exchange the lines between them and flashing it the same way like ATMEGA328P?

Answer (score 5):

The best way to answer this kind of question would be to check and compare the Datasheets or search for an application node like [this on](https://web.archive.org/web/20210326181211/https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1464/Atmel-42559-Differences-between-ATmega328P-and-ATmega328PB_ApplicationNote_AT15007.pdf) from the manufacturer where the differences are listed. We can see that several peripherals were added and therefor configuration registers added and that in the tqfp packages pin 3 & 6 are not power and gnd anymore. Also it can't handle a full swing crystal oscillator anymore.

Paragraph 3.3 states the timing differences for the parallel programming: The timings were slightly adjusted and they don't overlap. If you want to stay in spec you're probably going to need to adjust the timings for writing to the chip. This could however be done through the signature bytes which were also adjusted, so a programmer could automaticly adjust the timings if it is aware of this change.

In the End i would say yes it's possible, but you have to make sure not to short out Pins 3&6, you're not using the wrong crystal and you might need to adjust the timing for programming parallel slightly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Steven. i'm reading about full swing external oscillator and I don't understand very well what is that. On my design I'm using external 16 MHZ crystal oscillator and 18 pF capacitors. There shouldn't be any problem, right?

Comment: It depends. I'd like to refer you to section 11.3 of the atmega328PB Datasheet. The sum of the external, pin and stray capacitanc is supossed to be half the load capacitance of your crystal. The load capacitance for your crystal should be in it's datasheet.